# setLeftCapWidth on the mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Does anyone know how to use setLeftCapWidth on the mac? I know that Apple uses it in iChat and atebits uses it in Tweetie for mac. So does anyone know how to re-create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you want to do is draw button-like artwork that consists of a left image, a right image, and a tiled center image, then see [NSDrawThreePartImage](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSDrawThreePartImage).

Comment: I tried NSDrawThreePartImage but i cant get it to stop scaling the left cap (speech bubble) to resize the top cap while resizing the fill , same with the right cap of the bubble

Comment: I even tried NSDrawNinePartImage but i still cant seem to get it to scale right

Comment: The comments in the header describe exactly how everything is scaled.